# How to access a particular element in JLIST?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, windowbuilder

I am trying to push a selected value at index 'a' to index 'a+1'.

But if index 'a+1' is not empty, I have to swap the two values. For this, I do not know how to obtain the value at index 'a+1'. It is not selected. The JList API does not support random access.

How do I implement this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the elements in a `JList` you need to get hold of its `ListModel`.

The model has a [`getElementAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html#getElementAt(int)) method.

```
item = myJList.getModel().getElementAt(a+1);
```